# Length between two points on an arbitrary surface

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, geodesic, arc-length

Given a surface represented by the function $f(x,y):R^2 \rightarrow R$. I am trying to write a program that computes the distance between two points that belongs to that surface.

For example, say, the surface is represented by
$$f(x,y) = \dfrac{1}{\pi}\left(1 - \dfrac{x^2 + y^2}{2}\right)\exp\left(-\dfrac{x^2 + y^2}{2}\right)$$

And my points are $(-2,2, f(-2,2) )$ and $(2.2, 1.5, f(2.2,1.5))$, I am trying to compute the distance represented by the green line, which basically represents is like landing a tape on that surface between those two points

[image: function f(x,y) example]

My rusty math from college tells me that derivatives is the approach but not sure if that is in the right direction.

Comment: In standard usage that I'm aware of, surfaces are 2-dimensional, cannot be embedded in one dimension.

Comment: Note that what is usually meant by the distance between two points on a surface requires [geodesics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic), it's not enough to just "land a tape" arbitrarily.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\tau:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^k$ be an arbitrary smooth function. We partition $0=t_0<\ldots<t_n=1$ and try to approximate the length of the curve as the sum of the length of the line segments between consecutive $\tau(t_i)$ points. We use $\|\cdot\|$ to denote the length of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^k$. Let $\tau_1,\ldots, \tau_k$ be the coordinate functions of $\tau$, so $\tau(t)=(\tau_1(t), \ldots, \tau_k(t))$.

We have $$\|\tau(t_i)-\tau(t_{i-1})\|^2 = \sum_{j=1}^k |\tau_j(t_i)-\tau_j(t_{i-1})|^2.$$  For a very fine partition, we will have, roughly, that $$\tau_j(t_i)-\tau_j(t_{i-1})\approx \tau'_j(t_i)[t_i-t_{i-1}].$$ Therefore we have an approximation of the length as $$\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^k \tau'_j(t_i)^2}\cdot [t_i-t_{i-1}]=\sum_{i=1}^n \|\nabla \tau (t_i)\|[t_i-t_{i-1}],$$ where $\nabla \tau$ is the gradient $\nabla \tau(t)=(\tau'_1(t), \ldots, \tau'_k(t))$.

As the partitions become finer and finer, these are Riemann sums which converge to the integral $\int_0^1 \|\nabla \tau(t)\|dt$, which is the exact value of the arc length.

Fix $(x_0,y_0)$, $(x_1,y_1)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$. We want to travel over the surface, but above/below the straight line from $(x_0,y_0)$ to $(x_1,y_1)$.

Let $\tau_1(t)=(1-t)x_0+tx_1$, $\tau_2(t)=(1-t)y_0+ty_1$. Then $(\tau_1(t), \tau_2(t))$ traces out the line from $(x_0,y_0)$ to $(x_1,y_1)$ as $t$ goes from $0$ to $1$. For the $z$-coordinate, we need the height of the function: $$\tau_3(t) = f(\tau_1(t), \tau_2(t))= f((1-t)x_0+tx_1,(1-t)y_0+ty_1).$$

Note that $\tau'_1=x_1-x_0$, $\tau'_2=y_1-y_0$, and $$\tau'_3=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot [x_1-x_0]+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}[x_1-x_0].$$ This is a function of $t$, since $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is evaluated at the point $(x,y)=((1-t)x_0+tx_1,(1-t)y_0+ty_1)$.

The arc length is then $$\int_0^1 \sqrt{[x_1-x_0]^2+[y_1-y_0]^2+\biggl[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot [x_1-x_0]+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}[x_1-x_0]\biggr]^2}dt.$$

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. I walked through the steps, and I finally get it. now I am getting trouble coding it, I can certainly write the code for that specific function. but I would like to generalize this for any input function